# SharePoint server 2013 is running too slowly on VM workstation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, performance, vmware

I have the following specification for my development environment;

**Host Machine:-**

1. Windows 7 professional.
2. Core i7 (8 processes).
3. VM workstation.
4. 32 GB RAM.
5. 700 GB hard disk.

**On the VM:-**

1. Windows server 2008 r2.
2. SQL server 2008 r2.
3. SharePoint server 2013.
4. Visual studio 2012.
5. Team foundation server 2012.
6. 4 processes.
7. 24 GB RAM
8. 80 GB Hard disk.

But when I first install the VM it was fine and fast, but after working on SharePoint (creating new Apps, web applications, etc.) it become very slow, for example when I try to create new web application, I was not able to change the field’s values as the dialog become unresponsive. BUT THE only thing I did on my virtual machine is as follow:-

1. I first install the VM using the administrator account using the default domain for my machine.
2. And now I have create a new user which is login to our company domain and I am access the same VM create by the admin on the old domain, so might this cause the performance issue?

Thanks in advance for any help.
BR

Comment: what type of machine is it, e.g. server, laptop.. and how many hard disks are you using. also use ULS viewer to find out what happening behind scenes.

Comment: it is a laptop HP elitebook ,, with one hard disk.

Comment: Recommendation is to run on an SSD disk then you will notice and increase in performance.
Also try to only give the SQL Server 2 corse to work with this will ensure that there is always 2 core's for all the other processes.

Answer (score 1):

check:

take 8 processors, it is the recomendate;
add HD, minimal 100 GB, 80 GB is recomendate;
database should locate in diferent VHD, this is a good pratic (Because IO of disk).

Comment: add HD, minimal 100 GB, 80 GB is recomendate, database shoul locate in diferent VHD, this is a good pratice